# multiple checkbox filter in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-filter

So i have a search bar that have multiple `checkbox` that will filter the `ng-repeat` when i check any of the checkbox they will filter it but when i select another one it doesn't return anything ?

**Example**

[image]

Cancelled checkbox and Pending Approval has been checked!

Am i missing something ?

**displayedCollection value**

```
displayedCollection:[{ "employeeName" : "test user","status" : "Pending Approval"}]
```

**ng-repeat**

```
<label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" ng-model="cancelled" ng-true-value="'Cancelled'" ng-false-value="">
<span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
<span class="custom-control-description">Cancelled</span>
```

```
<label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" ng-model="pa" ng-true-value="'Pending Approval'" ng-false-value="">
<span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
<span class="custom-control-description">Pending Approval</span>
```

**html**

```
<tr ng-repeat="leave in displayedCollection | dateRanges:from:to | filter:cancelled | filter:pa">
<td class="text-capitalize">{{ leave.fullName }}</td>
<td>{{ leave.fromDate | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy'}} - {{ leave.toDate | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy' }}</td>
<td>{{ leave.leaveType }}</td>
<td>{{ }}</td>
<td class="text-center">{{ leave.leaveDays }}</td>
<td class="text-center">{{ leave.leaveStatus }}</td>
<td class="text-center">
    <i class="fa fa-comment-o" aria-hidden="true" data-target="#modalComment" data-toggle="modal" ng-click="vm.getComment(leave)"></i>
</td>
<td class="text-center">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-trans-blue btn-raised btn-xs btn-circle">
        <strong>
            <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h fa-1x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </strong>
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-trans-red btn-raised btn-xs btn-circle" ng-click="vm.deleteLeave(leave)">
        <i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-1x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </button>
</td></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

use the `||` (OR) operator on the filter.

```
<tr ng-repeat="leave in displayedCollection | dateRanges:from:to | filter: (cancelled || pa)">
```

Filter the data set according to the `status` property also

```
<li ng-repeat="account in accounts | filter:{status : pa ||cancelled  }">{{account}}</li>
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/uwb2s9tb/6/)

Comment: Tried your answer but it didn't fixed the problem.

Comment: Tried your updated answer its giving me an error with the daterange filter

Comment: i've updated the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uwb2s9tb/7/) of your answer its not applicable.